# How to manage (store) JWT in SPA (react) application to handle subsequent request after authentication

Tags: reactjs, jwt, identityserver4

I have a ASP.NET CORE API solution and I want to multiple clients (SPAs, mobil, MVC) can consume from that API. I intended to use IdentityServer4 to secure the API using JWTs. My question is where to store the token after a successful authentication if the Client is a React application?

Answer (score 0):

there are several options to store on client
1) Cookies
2) Local storage
3) React state (Redux for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a great package called [redux-react-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-react-session), which allows you to store you jwt in `'INDEXEDDB', 'WEBSQL', 'LOCALSTORAGE' or 'COOKIES'`.

You can choose the appropriate location depending on you needs and constraints.

Comment: Thank you Abdelkarim EL AMEL for your help!